# cron job executes php script successfully but fails to save files or make directories

Tags: php, cron, shared-hosting

I have a php script hosted in shared hosting server, I have created cron job to execute the script every 5m. Cron job executed the script as expected, however it fails to create directories and save files (when i execute it manually, it works).

here is my cron command:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/myusername/public_html/tild/index.php
```

here code that cron fails to run

```
mkdir (__DIR__ .'/testdir');
file_put_contents('testdir/1.jpg', file_get_contents($url_to_jpg));
```

I am hosting the file on Godaddy shared hosting

Comment: This is almost certainly a ownership problem. The user things are run under as cron is different than the web user.

Comment: check your apache or nginx user and change ownership of your files. if user is www-data `sudo chown www:data:www-data -R /root_path`

Comment: indeed, it was a permission issue, after i change the php script permission to 777, it works (before it was 700). Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Check file permissions, may be your script user doesn't have permission to create new dicrectory / file on specified location.

Answer (score 0):

You can check permission when running the cron. Most case, it's because of permission

Answer (score 0):

use chdir() or define a path using dirname ( **FILE** ) and use that in your mkdir () and file_put_contents ()

```
<?php

chdir ( __DIR__ );

mkdir ( '/testdir' );

file_put_contents ( 'testdir/1.jpg', file_get_contents ( $url_to_jpg ) );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone face the same problem in the future, the problem was with the permissions, to solve the problem change the permission of the php script file, it must have the write permission), to do that:

**1. Using FTP Client (i.e. Filezilla):**
right click on the script file, and choose File permission, give write permission to the user and group of users (i.e. 766)

**2. Using Terminal:**

```
chmod 766 /path/to/php_script
```